# How to stop animation for few time and then start again

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I want the container should remain on its middle for few times and then animate to positive offset when almost all container are arrived to middle.I have also tried with **tween** but this also does not work.I have tried using animation controller value to check and stop animation and start again,this also does not work.I want the animation containr come from negative offset,remain few times on middlet and then animated to positive offset

**updated**

```
   class _LoadingAnimationState extends State<LoadingAnimation>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController _controller;
  late List<Animation<Offset>> _sequenceAnimation;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: const Duration(seconds: 4));

    _sequenceAnimation = List.generate(5, (index) {
      print("begin index $index ${index/5}}");
        print("end index $index ${(index+1)/5}");
      return TweenSequence<Offset>(<TweenSequenceItem<Offset>>[
        TweenSequenceItem(
            tween: Tween(
              begin: const Offset(-300, 0),
              end: const Offset(0, 0),
            ),
            weight: 20),
        TweenSequenceItem(
            tween: Tween(
              begin: const Offset(0, 0),
              end: const Offset(300, 0),
            ),
            weight: 20),
      ]).animate(CurvedAnimation(
        reverseCurve: Curves.decelerate,
        parent: _controller,
        curve: Interval(
          index / 5,
          (index + 1) / 5,
          curve: Curves.slowMiddle,
        ),
      ));
    });

    _controller.addListener(() {
      if (_controller.value > 0.5 && _controller.value < 0.7) {
        _controller.stop();
        print("stop");
        Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2));
        _controller.forward();
        print("forwarrd");
        // Add a delay before starting the animation loop again
        // Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2), () {

        // });
      }
    });
    _controller.addStatusListener((status) {
      if (status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
        _controller.reset();
        _controller.forward();
      }
    });
    _controller.forward();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
      body: Center(
        child: Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Wrap(
              children: List.generate(5, (index) {
                return AnimatedBuilder(
                  animation: _controller,
                  builder: (context, child) {
                    return Transform.translate(
                      offset: _sequenceAnimation[index].value,
                      child: Container(
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                        width: 10,
                        height: 10,
                        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                          shape: BoxShape.circle,
                          color: Colors.blue, // Replace with your color
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                );
              }),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you research on Curves, You might want to create a custom curve as you will get more control over what you need in a neat way. [https://www.funwithflutter.dev/creating-custom-animation-curves-in-flutter/]

Comment: the provided page is not found

Comment: https://www.funwithflutter.dev/creating-custom-animation-curves-in-flutter/

Comment: I have already set the curve

Answer (score -1):

You can use this following code to get the desired output

```
class _LoadingAnimationState extends State<LoadingAnimation> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController _controller;
  late List<Animation<Offset>> _sequenceAnimation;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: const Duration(seconds: 5));

    _sequenceAnimation = List.generate(5, (index) {
      return Tween<Offset>(
        begin: const Offset(-300, 0),
        end: const Offset(300, 0),
      ).animate(CurvedAnimation(
        parent: _controller,
        curve: Interval((index / 5) + 0.1, (index + 1) / 5),
      ));
    });

    _controller.addListener(() {
      if (_controller.value > 0.9) {
        // Add a delay before starting the animation loop again
        Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2), () {
          _controller.reset();
          _controller.forward();
        });
      }
    });

    _controller.forward();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
      body: Center(
        child: Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Wrap(
              children: List.generate(5, (index) {
                return AnimatedBuilder(
                  animation: _controller,
                  builder: (context, child) {
                    return Transform.translate(
                      offset: _sequenceAnimation[index].value,
                      child: Container(
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                        width: 10,
                        height: 10,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          shape: BoxShape.circle,
                          color: Colors.blue, // Replace with your color
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                );
              }),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer,but this is not what i am actually looking for.I am looking for like this: https://codepen.io/NourimoS/pen/JwMPwb